# SQL the next nearest record

Tags: sql, mysql

I have table act_detail:

```
+------+------+--------+
| id   | name | action |
+------+------+--------+
|    1 | Tom  | eat    |
|    2 | Jack | eat    |
|    3 | Tom  | play   |
|    4 | Tom  | sleep  |
|    5 | Tom  | eat    |
|    6 | Jack | sleep  |
|    7 | Tom  | sleep  |
|    8 | Tom  | eat    |
+------+------+--------+
```

I want get the summery of "eat" and the next nearest "sleep" information with the same name:

```
+------+--------+----------+
| name | eat_id | sleep_id |
+------+--------+----------+
| Tom  |      1 |        4 |
| Jack |      2 |        6 |
| Tom  |      5 |        7 |
| Tom  |      8 |     NULL |
+------+--------+----------+
```

I find I can get the result with the SQL below:

```
SELECT 
    a.name, 
    a.id AS eat_id, 
    (SELECT MIN(id) FROM act_detail b WHERE a.name = b.name AND b.id > a.id AND b.action = 'sleep') AS sleep_id 
FROM act_detail a 
WHERE a.action = 'eat'
ORDER BY a.id;
```

But this SQL need sub-query and need more sub-query when need get more columns in table b. It will be very slow with lots of records.
Suppose we can add any index.
Is there any effective method to solve this problem with standard SQL(Maybe one left join,one temporary table and one group by statement)?

Comment: not only is it a subquery, it's a correlated subquery, so you're running that subquery for EVERY row in the parent query. but there isn't really a way around it, because your "next higher sleep_id" requirement demands it.

Comment: What is 'lots of records'? Remember: what is slow for a computer is often fast enough for us. And what is lots for us, is often a little for a computer.

Comment: Seems like you could have `ORDER BY id` and `LIMIT 1` in your subquery and then get rid of `MIN()`. Proper indexes would help of course.

Comment: @MarcB I think the accepted answer is one effective method for this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a sub query:-

```
SELECT a.name, a.id AS eat_id, MIN(b.id) AS sleep_id
FROM act_detail a
LEFT OUTER JOIN act_detail b 
ON a.name = b.name
AND b.action = 'sleep'
AND b.id > a.id
WHERE a.action = 'eat'
GROUP BY a.name, eat_id
ORDER BY a.id;
```

SQL fiddle for it here:-

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/11834/2

Answer (score 1):

First get all eat actions and all sleep actions. Join both so that names match and sleep occurs after eating. Then find the minimum distance and add that distance.

```
select eat.name, eat.id as eat_id, eat.id + min(sleep.id - eat.id) as sleep_id
from
(
  select id 
  from act_detail
  where action = 'eat'
) eat
left join
(
  select id 
  from act_detail
  where action = 'sleep'
) sleep on sleep.name = eat.name and sleep.id > eat.id
group by eat.name, eat.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this slight change to avoid the aggregate function (which scans through multiple subquery records per record):

```
SELECT 
    a.name, 
    a.id AS eat_id, 
    (SELECT b.id FROM act_detail b
     WHERE b.action = 'sleep'
       AND b.name = a.name
       AND b.id > a.id
     ORDER BY b.id
     LIMIT 1) AS sleep_id 
FROM act_detail a 
WHERE a.action = 'eat'
ORDER BY a.id;
```

With the following "covering" index:

```
act_detail(action, name, id)
```

If this is InnoDB and `id` is your primary key, then you can drop `id` from the above index.